# 301 or 302 Redirection With PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

I'm considering using the following code during a website launch phase to show users a *down for maintenance* page while showing me the rest of the site.

Is there a way to show the correct 302 re-direction status to search engines or should I look for another `.htaccess` based approach?

```
$visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (preg_match("/192.168.0.1/",$visitor)) {
    header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/thank-you.html');
} else {
    header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/home-page.html');
};
```

Comment: Remember to `exit` your script after these headers

Answer (score 158, accepted):

For a `302 Found`, i.e. a temporary redirect do:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/home-page.html');
// OR: header('Location: http://www.example.com/home-page.html', true, 302);
exit;
```

If you need a permanent redirect, aka: `301 Moved Permanently`, do:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/home-page.html', true, 301);
exit;
```

For more info check the PHP manual for the [header function <sup>Doc</sup>](http://php.net/header). Also, don't forget to call `exit;` when using `header('Location: ');`

But, considering you are doing a temporary maintenance (you don't want that search engines index your page) it's advised to return a `503 Service Unavailable` with a custom message (i.e. you don't need any redirect):

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable");
header("Status: 503 Service Unavailable");
header("Retry-After: 3600");
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Temporarily Unavailable</title>
<meta name="robots" content="none" />
</head>
<body>
   Your message here.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The syntax is `void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: OP asked for redirect during maintenance, in that case he must do temporary redirect with 302, not 301. In case of 301 aka permanent redirect, browser will never try that page but go to redirected one.

Comment: @michaeld Never, ever test placeholder code as if it were production code. It doesn’t matter what example URL is used in an answer—you should always substitute your own, known URL in its place before running the code.

Comment: The point is: should we redirect the client with a 302 and then issue a 503 page, or should we just set up a rewrite rule which would issue a 503 page directly to each client's request?

Answer (score 20):

The following code will issue a 301 redirect.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/', true, 301);
exit;
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it really matters how you do it, from PHP or htaccess. Both will accomplish the same thing.

The one thing I want to point out is whether you want the search engines begin to index your site in this "maintenance" phase or not. If **not**, you could use the status code `503` ("temporarily down"). Here's a htaccess example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^192\.168\.0\.1
ErrorDocument 503 /redirect-folder/index.html
RewriteRule !^s/redirect-folder$ /redirect-folder [L,R=503]
```

In PHP:

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/redirect-folder/index.html', true, 503);
exit;
```

With the current PHP redirect code you're using, the redirect is a `302` (default).

Comment: I'm not sure PHP (or the underlying server, in turn) will allow an 503 status code through along with the `Location` header! In fact, I'm almost sure [it wouldn't](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). (I also vaguely recall I had a similar mistake when writing a proxy.) You should most likely use the `header("HTTP/1.0 503 Service not available");` form as also shown in @dynamic's example.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check what header you're getting? Because you should be getting a `302` with above.

From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.

so you are already doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

save this file in the same directory as .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

# To show 404 page 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

# Permanent redirect
Redirect 301 /util/old.html /util/new.php

# Temporary redirect
Redirect 302 /util/old.html /util/new.php
```