# AJAX request redirection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I apologize for my bad english :)

I'm doing php file with ajax request. json response comes in the format of. but in some cases can be redirect. In this case I want the redirect of the page.

Could you please help me. Thank's.

Example PHP File :

```
<?php
$status = $_POST['status'];

if($status == 'a'){
    // return json response
}else{
   echo "<form action='http://www.url.com'>..</form><script type='text/javascript'>form.submit();</script>";
}
?>
```

Example JS File :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://www.my_php_file.com'
});
```

Comment: how response type both can be json as wel HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can issue the redirect in the usual way, by returning a `3xx` response with a `Location` header. The browser will follow the redirect (it doesn't make the JavaScript code doing the ajax call handle it).

So for instance, if you want to issue a `301` ("permanent moved"):

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com',true,301);
exit;
```

(I didn't know the specifics of how to issue the `3xx` in PHP, but found them [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9363803/157247)).

Side note: I doubt `www.google.com` is going to work, I assume that was just an example.

Comment: @muratsac: You've changed it into a *different* question, frankly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";` to issue a redirect via JS.

Answer (score 0):

In your php file replace php redirection with javascript redirection like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
</script>
```