# Prevent CURL to access to specific pages

Tags: php, html, curl

My `index.php` includes `header.php` and `footer.php` by this way:

```
define("LEGAL_PATH", TRUE);
include("header.php");
// ...
include("footer.php");
```

And each of my included files begins with:

```
if (!defined("LEGAL_PATH"))
{
    header("location: index.php");
    exit(0);
}
```

For the moment, when we load the `header.php` (or `footer.php`), we are redirected on the `index.php` page. When we try to curl the `header.php`, it returns a blank page (thanks to the `exit(0)`).

**Question:**

Regarding bad people, I would like to generate a 404 error (as when we try to access to `efjiozfjoijefiojzeof.php` for instance) even if we load the page with curl: in this case (with a curl command), the header location is nonfonctionnal.

The curl output which I had (when there is no `exit(0)`):

```
$> curl https://www.mywebsite.com/header.php
NOBODY SHOULD READ THIS DIRECTLY FROM HEADER.PHP FILE
```

The curl output which I currently have (when there is the `exit(0)`):

```
$> curl https://www.mywebsite.com/header.php
$>
```

The curl output which I would like to have:

```
$> curl https://www.mywebsite.com/header.php
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /headzefjzefjp.php was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
$>
```

My idea was to include the 404 page file, but when I curl in verbose mode, I still have a 200 error code (and not a 404):

```
$> curl https://.../header.php -v
...
> GET /header.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: ...
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

So, what is the good way to really ignore the header.php file (from browsers, curl, etc)?

Comment: `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` - Must be called before you display any content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to prevent people from accessing pages they are not supposed to access (like your header, footer or some libraries) is to put them outside of your document root.

For example your folder structure could be like:

```
documentroot/index.php
header.php
footer.php
```

And your `index.php` would look like:

```
<?php 
require('../header.php');
echo "some content";
require('../footer.php');
```

Instead of trying to return a 404 error, this is the easiest and most secure way to prevent users from accessing pages they are not supposed to access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send `404 Not Found` manually. See this answer for that
[How can I create an error 404 in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381123/how-can-i-create-an-error-404-in-php)

Also, if you are redirecting, you need to set a 301 or 302 status. [301 or 302 Redirection With PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363760/301-or-302-redirection-with-php) Which you are doing implicitly when using "location" header

Another thing is to make sure that cURL is not following 30x redirects. (maybe your curl is an alias to `curl -l`)
Try using `curl --max-redirects=0 https://www.mywebsite.com/header.php` to see if that is the case.